# Using JDBC to implement username and password authentication

Tags: java, mysql

I'm using JDBC to check a database for a username and password to grant login access to my gui, but when I'm trying to test that the JDBC is working its not blocking access when the wrong username and password is entered..

Below is my code, I believe its connecting the the database correctly, as when i press the login button it outputs Running Check Login and User is validated.

```
class usernamecheck {

    static final String DATABASE_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql";
    static final String USERNAME = "root";
    static final String PASSWORD = "root";

   // launch the application
    public static boolean checkLogin(String username, String password)
            throws SQLException {
        System.out.print("Running Check Login \n");

        Connection connection = null; // manages connection
        PreparedStatement pt = null; // manages prepared statement

        // connect to database usernames and query database
        try {

            // establish connection to database
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(DATABASE_URL, "root", "root");

            // query database
            pt = con.prepareStatement("select userName,password from mysql.person where userName=?");

            // process query results
            pt.setString(1, username);
            ResultSet rs = pt.executeQuery();
            String orgUname = "", orPass = "";
            while (rs.next()) {
                orgUname = rs.getString("userName");
                orPass = rs.getString("password");
            } //end while
            if (orPass.equals(password)) {
                //do something
                return true;
            } else {
                //do something
            }
        }//end try
        catch (Exception e) {
        } //end catch  
        return false;
    } //end main
}
```

Code with GUI

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.sql.*;


public class Login extends JFrame {

    private JTextField jtfUsername, jtfPassword;
    private JButton backButton, loginButton;
    private JMenuItem jmiLogin, jmiBack, jmiHelp, jmiAbout;

    Login() {
        //create menu bar
        JMenuBar jmb = new JMenuBar();

        //set menu bar to the applet
        setJMenuBar(jmb);

        //add menu "operation" to menu bar
        JMenu optionsMenu = new JMenu("Options");
        optionsMenu.setMnemonic('O');
        jmb.add(optionsMenu);

        //add menu "help"
        JMenu helpMenu = new JMenu("Help");
        helpMenu.setMnemonic('H');
        helpMenu.add(jmiAbout = new JMenuItem("About", 'A'));
        jmb.add(helpMenu);

        //add menu items with mnemonics to menu "options"
        optionsMenu.add(jmiLogin = new JMenuItem("Login", 'L'));
        optionsMenu.addSeparator();
        optionsMenu.add(jmiBack = new JMenuItem("Back", 'B'));

        //panel p1 to holds text fields
        JPanel p1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 2));
        p1.add(new JLabel("Username"));
        p1.add(jtfUsername = new JTextField(15));
        p1.add(new JLabel("Password"));
        p1.add(jtfPassword = new JPasswordField(15));

        //panel p2 to holds buttons
        JPanel p2 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        p2.add(backButton = new JButton("Back"));
        p2.add(loginButton = new JButton("Login"));

        //Panel with image??????

        //add panels to frame
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 1));
        panel.add(p1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel.add(p2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setTitle("Main Page");


        //listners for exit menuitem and button
        jmiBack.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Welcome welcome = new Welcome();
                welcome.setVisible(true);
                welcome.setSize(500, 500);
                welcome.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                registerInterface regFace = new registerInterface();
                regFace.setVisible(false);
                Login.this.dispose();
                Login.this.setVisible(false);
            }
        });

        backButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Welcome welcome = new Welcome();
                welcome.setVisible(true);
                welcome.setSize(500, 500);
                welcome.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                registerInterface regFace = new registerInterface();
                regFace.setVisible(false);
                Login.this.dispose();
                Login.this.setVisible(false);
            }
        });

        //listner for about menuitem
        jmiAbout.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                        "This is the login panel"
                        + "\n Assignment for University",
                        "About", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }
        });

        //action listeners for Login in button and menu item
        loginButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    usernamecheck.checkLogin(jtfUsername.getText(), jtfPassword.getText()); {
                    System.out.println("User is validated");
               }
                } catch (SQLException se) {
                }
                MainMenu mainmenu = new MainMenu();
                mainmenu.setVisible(true);
                mainmenu.setSize(500, 500);
                mainmenu.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                registerInterface regFace = new registerInterface();
                regFace.setVisible(false);
                Login.this.dispose();
                Login.this.setVisible(false);
            }
        });

        jmiLogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                MainMenu mainmenu = new MainMenu();
                mainmenu.setVisible(true);
                mainmenu.setSize(500, 500);
                mainmenu.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                registerInterface regFace = new registerInterface();
                regFace.setVisible(false);
                Login.this.dispose();
                Login.this.setVisible(false);
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        Login frame = new Login();
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
class usernamecheck {

    static final String DATABASE_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql";
    static final String USERNAME = "root";
    static final String PASSWORD = "root";


   // launch the application
    public static boolean checkLogin(String username, String password)
            throws SQLException {
        System.out.print("Running Check Login \n");

        Connection connection = null; // manages connection
        PreparedStatement pt = null; // manages prepared statement
        Statement stmt = null;
        String query="select userName from person where userName = ? and password = ?";


        // connect to database usernames and query database
        try {

            // establish connection to database
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(DATABASE_URL, "root", "root");

            // query database
            pt = con.prepareStatement("select userName from person where userName = ? and password = ?");
           
            // process query results
            pt.setString(1, username);
            ResultSet rs = pt.executeQuery(query);
            String orgUname = "", orPass = "";
            while (rs.next()) {
                orgUname = rs.getString("userName");
                orPass = rs.getString("password");
            } //end while
            if (orPass.equals(password) && orgUname.equals(username)) {
                //do something
                return false;
            } else {
                //do something
                return true;
            }
        }//end try
        catch (Exception e) {
        } //end catch  
        return true;
    } //end main
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `checkLogin()` method returns true if everything is OK, and false otherwise. But you don't check the result of the method in your UI, and thus proceed even if it returned false.

The code should do

```
try {
    boolean loggedIn = usernamecheck.checkLogin(jtfUsername.getText(), jtfPassword.getText());
    if (!loggedIn) {
        displayErrorMessage("Sorry, wrong credentials");
        return;
    }
}
catch (SQLException se) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    displayErrorMessage("Sorry, couldn't check your credentials. Check the logs and report the problem to an administrator.");
    return;
}
```

Comment: This seems to be working, but when I'm inputting the correct information it's not letting me in.